# JS to TS: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeguards

I am new to TypeScript and have just started migrating my application from JavaScript to TypeScript.

1. First function: `calcAvg`, takes an array of numbers and returns their average.
2. Second function: `avgRoasDiscrepancy`, takes two arrays, if the two arrays are of equal length and with no null values, it will subtract each element from one list with the element in the same index from the second array.

The issue is in the following `map` function (see full code below):

```
const discArray = clientRoasArray.map((value: number, index: number) => value - roasArray[index]);
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '(value: number, index: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: number | null, index: number, array: (number | null)[]) => number'.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

I don't know how to "convince" TypeScript that both `value` and `roasArray[index]` are in fact numbers and not nulls.

Here is the complete code :

```
interface DailyData {
  id: number
  clientCost:number
  conValue:number
  clientConvValue:number
  margin: number

}

const calcAvg = (dataList: number[]) => {
  const reducer = (accumulator: number, curr: number) => accumulator + curr;
  const dataSum = dataList.reduce(reducer, 0);
  return dataSum / dataList.length;
};


const avgRoasDiscrepancy = (advertiserStats: DailyData[]) => {
  const clientRoasArray = advertiserStats.map((obj: DailyData) => obj.clientCost > 0 ? obj.clientConvValue/obj.clientCost: null);
  const roasArray = advertiserStats.map((obj: DailyData) => obj.clientCost > 0 ? obj.conValue/obj.clientCost: null);
  if (clientRoasArray.length === 0 || roasArray.length === 0) {
    return 'no data'
  }
  if (!!clientRoasArray.every((el: number|null) => el!== null) || (!roasArray.every((el: number|null) => el!== null) )) {
    //if one of the arrays has null values don't calculate
    return 'no data';
  }
  if (clientRoasArray.length === roasArray.length) {
    const discArray = clientRoasArray.map((value: number, index: number) => value - roasArray[index]);
    return calcAvg(discArray as number[]);
  }
  return 'no data';

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get type inference to work properly using the `every` calls on the arrays, however you can make a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to help the compiler understand that the arrays are of type `number[]` instead of `(number | null)[]`. This will also help with refactoring a bit.

Note that there's also an issue with your current type checking logic, but looks like it's just a typo: the `!!` before the first condition should just be a single `!`.

Here's a simple type guard:

```
function isNonNullNumberArray(x: (number | null)[]): x is number[] {
    return x.every(e => e !== null);
}
```

Then you can use `isNonNullNumberArray` like this:

```
  if (!(isNonNullNumberArray(clientRoasArray) && isNonNullNumberArray(roasArray))) {
    //if one of the arrays has null values don't calculate
    return 'no data';
  }
  // now the compiler knows that neither array contains null values
  if (clientRoasArray.length === roasArray.length) {
    const discArray = clientRoasArray.map((value: number, index: number) => value - roasArray[index]);
    return calcAvg(discArray);
  }
  return 'no data';
```

You could make a more general type guard like this too if you wanted using generics so that it works for types other than `number`:

```
function isNonNullArray<T>(x: T[]): x is Exclude<T, null>[] {
    return x.every(e => e !== null);
}
```

By the way, you don't need to explicitly declare parameter types in functions passed to `map` and other array method as the compiler can infer the types based on the signature of the array method (e.g. `map`).

Answer (score 3):

In this line

```
  const clientRoasArray = advertiserStats.map((obj: DailyData) => obj.clientCost > 0 ? obj.clientConvValue/obj.clientCost: null);
```

You are assuming that the elements of clientRoasArray could be `number` or could be `null` and this is clear in your condition `: null`

And in this line, you are identifying the value of the `clientRoasArray` as `number only` which is wrong because you told your code that the value could be `number|null`

All you need is to change  this line

```
const discArray = clientRoasArray.map((value: number, index: number) => value - roasArray[index]);
```

to this

```
const discArray = clientRoasArray.map((value: number | null, index: number) => value - roasArray[index]);
```

but you will face an issue with `roasArray[index]` because it also could be `null`

Comment: or even put `!` this symbol next to `value` like this, `value!`, so it will ignore that fact, value can be `null`

Answer (score 1):

You could check if your variable is not `null` and use `!` (non-null assertion operator) to tell TypeScript the expression can not be `null`. Also the type for `value` is `number | null`.

```js
if (clientRoasArray.length === roasArray.length) {
  const discArray = clientRoasArray.map((value: number | null, index: number) => {
    return value && roasArray[index] ? value - roasArray[index]! : null
  });
  return calcAvg(discArray as number[]);
}
```